Changing colored cell in GridPane in JavaFX
I want to write code, that can do following:

Create 9*9 GridPane board that filled with 81 StackPanes.

When I click on cell (StackPane) I want to change color of background StackPane to blue if it is white. If I have alreday had blue cell on board, than old cell becomes white and new one becomes blue. So, In anytime I can only have 0 or 1 colored cell.

I tried to use Array[9][9] of StackPanes but I failed because even if I declare this array before "public void start(Stage stage)" I fail to use each StackPane in lambda expressions or innerclasses.

I tried to use variable that tells if I have 1 colored cell or not and coordinates of colored cell in 2 variables. When I click on cells I see that coordinates works, but I can't change color of Panes.



package com.example.testingcolorswitching;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {


    boolean isAnyPaneSelected = true; // true if 1 of cells is selected
    int xColored = 1; // holds X coordinate of Selected cell;
    int yColored = 1; // holds Y coordinate of Selected cell;
    int columnSize = 50;
    int rowSize = 50;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();

        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++){
                StackPane cell = new StackPane();
                cell.setMinSize(columnSize, rowSize);
                
                // I would like that this was checked every time I click on GridPane 
                if (isAnyPaneSelected && x == xColored && y == yColored)
                    cell.setStyle("-fx-background-color:BLUE");

                final int thisX = x;
                final int thisY = y;

                cell.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {
                    if(isAnyPaneSelected) {
                        if (thisX == xColored & thisY == yColored)
                            isAnyPaneSelected = false;
                        else {
                            xColored = thisX;
                            yColored = thisY;
                        }
                    } else {
                        isAnyPaneSelected = true;
                        xColored = thisX;
                        yColored = thisY;
                    }

                    System.out.println(isAnyPaneSelected + " " + xColored + " " + yColored);
                });

                grid.add(cell, x, y);
            }


        // code below is not important. This code adds lines on screen.
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
            Line line = new Line(0.0, rowSize * i, rowSize * 9, rowSize * i);
            line.setManaged(false);
            if (i % 3 == 0)
                line.setStrokeWidth(3);

            else
                line.setStrokeWidth(1);
            grid.getChildren().add(line);

            line = new Line(columnSize * i, 0.0, columnSize * i, columnSize * 9);
            line.setManaged(false);
            if (i % 3 == 0)
                line.setStrokeWidth(3);

            else
                line.setStrokeWidth(1);
            grid.getChildren().add(line);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 600, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}



See: How to implement selection of Nodes in JavaFX

One way to fix this is by including the cell to an ObjectProperty and then you can add listener to add/remove the style of the cell.
Something like:
// Create an object property to hold the selected cell.
private ObjectProperty<StackPane> selectedCell = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

// Add listener to the object property to toggle the style
selectedCell.addListener((obs, old, val) -> {
    if (old != null) {
        old.setStyle(null);
    }
    if (val != null) {
        val.setStyle("-fx-background-color:BLUE");
    }
});

// On click, set the cell to the objectproperty.
cell.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {
    // If already selected, then remove it.
    if (cell.equals(selectedCell.get())) {
        selectedCell.set(null);
    } else {
        selectedCell.set(cell);
    }
});

Having said that, I also suggest to alter the logic of showing the lines. It really doesnt seem right adding unmanaged lines and positioning them in GridPane. I included a logic to add borders to each cell to get the final result (below image).

Below is  a complete demo of both the changes:

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CellColouringDemo extends Application {

    public static final String CSS = "data:text/css," + // language=CSS
            """
                        .outer-box{
                            -fx-border-style:solid;
                            -fx-border-color:black;
                            -fx-border-width:3px 0px 0px 3px;
                        }
                        
                        .cell{
                            -fx-border-style:solid;
                            -fx-border-color:black;
                            -fx-border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
                        }
                        
                        .cell-right{
                            -fx-border-width:0px 3px 1px 0px;
                        }
                        .cell-bottom{
                            -fx-border-width:0px 1px 3px 0px;
                        }
                        .cell-corner{
                            -fx-border-width:0px 3px 3px 0px;
                        }
                        
                        .selected-cell{
                            -fx-background-color: blue;
                        }
                    """;
    private int columnSize = 50;
    private int rowSize = 50;

    private ObjectProperty<StackPane> selectedCell = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    record Pos(int col, int row){}

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        selectedCell.addListener((obs, old, val) -> {
            if (old != null) {
                old.getStyleClass().remove("selected-cell");
                Pos pos = (Pos) old.getUserData();
                // Do further logic with previous cell position
            }
            if (val != null) {
                val.getStyleClass().add("selected-cell");
                Pos pos = (Pos) val.getUserData();
                // Do further logic with current cell position
            }
        });
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.getStyleClass().add("outer-box");
        for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
                StackPane cell = new StackPane();
                cell.setUserData(new Pos(col, row));
                cell.getStyleClass().add("cell");
                setCellStyle(cell, row, col);
                cell.setMinSize(columnSize, rowSize);
                cell.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {
                    if (cell.equals(selectedCell.get())) {
                        selectedCell.set(null);
                    } else {
                        selectedCell.set(cell);
                    }
                });
                grid.add(cell, col, row);
            }
        }
        StackPane root = new StackPane(new Group(grid));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(CSS);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void setCellStyle(StackPane cell, int row, int col) {
        boolean isBottom = (row + 1) % 3 == 0;
        boolean isRight = (col + 1) % 3 == 0;
        if (isBottom && isRight) {
            cell.getStyleClass().add("cell-corner");
        } else if (isBottom) {
            cell.getStyleClass().add("cell-bottom");
        } else if (isRight) {
            cell.getStyleClass().add("cell-right");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}


I like this, but I have three thoughts about it:
First, presumably there's also going to be some kind of actual application logic that's involved with the cell selection, meaning that it's not just going to be a visual "change the cell to blue" function but do something else.  So having a Property isn't going to translate well to some kind of application logic.  You'll need to have some data model that underlies it and the on/off logic should translate to that.

Second:  If there is some application logic behind this, then perhaps it should be handling the turning off of the other cell.  Is the idea that only one cell can be blue at a time a purely visual thing, or is it application logic.  What if the logic changes such that the previously blue cell turns red, instead?  If so, it shouldn't be in the screen logic.

Third, there's only 81 cells.  Wouldn't it be easier to just turn them all back to white - even if 80 of them are already white - and then turn the new one blue?  Why complicate things with Properties and Listeners to optimize it if the straight-forward approach can be used?

@ DaveB, I addressed the issue what the OP has asked. There can be other requirements he may need to address which he need to specify in question. Anyway with slight modifications ,we can encapsulate the cell details in the node for further application logic. (updated in answer). And for  the third point, I will definitely NOT agree with that :). I will not do re styling of all cells for every click.

Thank you for your code. It turned out to be very difficult for me. It seems I have to study theory more to know different options of JavaFX. I haven't studied some parts of it yet. Therefore, it took several days to figure out how ObjectProperty works and how to use the "record". Even to this day I haven't fully figured it out.

JavaFX has a class that deals with this kind of situation: ToggleGroup.  Out of the box there are only three classes that support the interface, Toggle, required to use ToggleGroup.  Those classes are RadioButton, RadioMenuItem and ToggleButton.
Technically, it's possible to style a ToggleButton to do pretty much what the OP wants, but the question was about StackPane.  So what does it take to make StakePane support Toggle and work with a ToggleGroup?
The Toggle interface basically consists of methods to support two Properties: a BooleanProperty to indicate that it has been selected, and an ObjectProperty<ToggleGroup> to indicate that it is in a ToggleGroup.  This requires the delegated setter and getter for the value, and a property getter for each property.  The selected property needs to be linked to a CSS PseudoClass in order to handle the styling.
Not mentioned in the JavaDocs, but important, is that the selected property needs to interact with the ToggleGroup.selectedToggle property in order to work.  This involves adding a Listener or a Subscription to the property to update the ToggleGroup when it changes.
Here's a class extending StackPane and implementing Toggle with the connection to the ToggleGroup.  This is Kotlin, but there's nothing so strange here that Java people can't follow it.  This was also compiled with JFX21, which includes Subscription:
class ToggleStackPane : StackPane(), Toggle {
    companion object {
        private val PSEUDO_CLASS_SELECTED: PseudoClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("selected")
    }

    private val toggleGroup: ObjectProperty<ToggleGroup?> = SimpleObjectProperty()
    private var selected: BooleanProperty = SimpleBooleanProperty(false)

    init {
        styleClass += "toggle-stackpane"
        selected.subscribe(Runnable {
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PSEUDO_CLASS_SELECTED, selected.value)
            getToggleGroup()?.let {
                if (selected.value) {
                    it.selectToggle(this)
                } else if (it.selectedToggle === this) {
                    it.selectToggle(null)
                }
            }
        })
    }

    override fun getToggleGroup(): ToggleGroup? = toggleGroup.value

    override fun setToggleGroup(p0: ToggleGroup?) {
        toggleGroup.value = p0
    }

    override fun toggleGroupProperty() = toggleGroup

    override fun isSelected(): Boolean = selected.value

    override fun setSelected(p0: Boolean) {
        selected.value = p0
    }

    override fun selectedProperty() = selected
}

The init{} section is much like a constructor, and it links the selected property to the PseudoClass and the ToggleGroup.  The ?.let{} only executes if toggleGroup is not empty (value is not Null).
ToggleGroup itself handles the work of ensuring that only one Toggle is selected at any given time, so we don't need to worry about it.
That's it, this is now a StackPane that supports Toggle and can be included into a ToggleGroup.
Here's a CSS file to go with it:
.toggle-stackpane {
   -fx-border-width: 1px;
   -fx-border-color: blue;
   -fx-min-width: 30px;
   -fx-min-height: 30px;
}

.toggle-stackpane: selected {
   -fx-border-width: 2px;
   -fx-background-color: lightblue;
}

Here's an application that will demonstrate how it works, close to the original use case as described by the OP:
class TogglesApplication : Application() {
    override fun start(stage: Stage) {
        stage.scene = Scene(createContent(), 340.0, 300.0).apply {
            TogglesApplication::class.java.getResource("toggles.css")?.toString()?.let { stylesheets += it }
        }
        stage.show()
    }

    private fun createContent(): Region = GridPane().also { gridPane ->
        val toggleGroup = ToggleGroup()
        for (x in 0..8) {
            for (y in 0..8) {
                val pane = ToggleStackPane().apply {
                    styleClass += "toggle-stackpane"
                    setOnMouseClicked { isSelected = true }
                    isPickOnBounds = true
                    toggleGroup.toggles.add(this)
                    gridPane.add(this, x, y)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun main() = Application.launch(TogglesApplication::class.java)

As you can see, it's fairly trivial.  The StackPanes are instantiated, styled and added to the GridPane, and then added to the ToggleGroup.  setOnMouseClicked() and isPickOnBounds = true are all you need to make the StackPanes clickable.
Additionally, since selected is a Property it can be bound bidirectionally to an element in a Presentation Model and therefore can be read or updated from application logic outside of the GUI code.
